# UITextField change event does not fire for speech or pasted input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitextfield

In Xcode 6.2 when trying to get a UITextField 'Editing Changed' event or 'Value Changed' event to fire when text is input using the Speech button from the keyboard, it works perfectly using typed input *but not when the input is either pasted or entered using speech recognition*.

Comment: Have you tried adding UITextField delegate methods? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Comment: Yes. That was the key.  Thank you.  I used shouldChangeCharactersINRange and that fired when the Speech button was used. @dichen

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use or hack another delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange, it get called when text is changing

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{    
    // Do your stuff or raise a event when it is Pasted.
    // You can figure out if isPasted from the pattern of range.

    return YES;
}
```